# Does the Linux Kernel access HW through BIOS, or does it directly interface with the HW?

Tags: kernel, boot, bios

From my understanding, BIOS 1) initializes HW and 2) jumps to a location and loads a boot loader into RAM.
When the BIOS does the initialization of HW, it must be running some routines (i.e. setting proper register bits, delays, etc...).
The questions I'm asking is if those BIOS routines are:

1. Are BIOS routines called by Linux Kernel or do Linux Kernel drivers reimplement the necessary routines?
2. Also is BIOS written in Assembly or is it some Hardware-Defined Language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It depends. In most cases, the kernel drives hardware directly, without going through the system firmware; but it does rely on firmware-provided functions in some cases (*e.g.* through ACPI).
2. The original PC BIOS was written in assembly language (the source code was included in IBM’s technical reference manuals). Current PC system firmware is mostly written in C, see [TianoCore](https://www.tianocore.org/).